# Stopping client seeing cached webpage

Tags: php, browser-cache

Ive found this tricky to word so please bear with me.

When I'm updating a website and I ask the client to see the changes, they always see the cached result from last time. Now this isn't a problem as I can ask them to ctrl f5 to refresh all the cache.

My question is, is there a way that I can force the client browser to refresh all of the content automatically? and what is the usual standard on this? I want to still use cache as this speeds up the website, just be able to tell it when it has updated.

I know for javascript files and css files you can change the name of the file so the browser treats it as a new file and re-downloads it e.g. myCssFilev1.2.css but what about the actual HTML?

Comment: I think you can use cache parameters in html headers http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of meta tags to do this:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

The cache-control, expires and pragma settings all work in different browsers, so it's best to include all of them. That should solve your problem.

**EDIT**

As Ariel has noted, you have to be careful with this. If this is a high-load situation, you probably want to find another solution. You can try to find the "middle ground", but tweaking the parameters (setting expires or cache-control's max-age to some value). However, if you don't have an insane server load, then this should be fine.

Comment: Yah, don't do that unless you want nothing at all to be cached. And you don't want that! (Unless you like very slow pages.)

Comment: Ariel, the question is "is there a way that I can force the client browser to refresh all of the content automatically". That means no chaching, I'm afraid.

Comment: At least don't set the expiration to instant. A 1 day - or even 1 hour cache will help tremendously.

Comment: One other thing: If this is a PHP page, don't set these in meta elements, use the `header()` function. For HTML pages meta elements are easier.

Comment: thanks all, I think what works best is to set a short expires time like ariel says, but through htaccess you can set different file types to different expires times. So the html can be set to very low  and images to be set higher. The user wont see instant refreshes but I think its workable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Say you have a javascript include.

Do:

```
<SCRIPT src="file.js?<?=filemtime('file.js')?>"></SCRIPT>
```

What this does is add the file modification time to the url for the file. So when you change the file, to the browser it will look like a new file, and won't be cached.

Be aware that the constant `filemtime` calls may slow things down.

You can use a combination of `dirname()` `__FILE__` and `PHP_SELF` to auto calculate the physical file page from the relative one, and then put it in a function so you don't have to type the filename manually twice yourself.

Comment: Note that OP says "I know for javascript files and css files you can change the name of the file so the browser treats it as a new file and re-downloads it e.g. myCssFilev1.2.css but what about the actual HTML?". What you are suggesting is for JS and CSS, not for HTML.

Comment: @dow You can do the exact same thing for the html file - you just put this code in links to the html pages. That's why I suggested writing a function to make it fast and easy.

Comment: How about the page where people "land" then? Automatically redirect to PHP_SELF?[randomnum] using mod_rewrite? That's a bit over the top isn't it? Interesting idea though.

Comment: @Dow Why not? And you don't need mod_rewrite, you can have PHP do it. For extra credit have PHP read the filemtime url field you passed in, and if it doesn't match the current mod time for the file cause a reload with `header('Location:..)`. Then you don't need to worry about bookmarked links. You can even leave out the field from links, just leave them bare, then have PHP check if the field was sent in the url, if not cause it to reload just like it would for an old field (although this will slow things down by constantly doing double requests on every link, and it only works on PHP pages).

Answer (score 0):

It's trickier than it appears. I honestly think that instructing the user to empty his browser's cache is the most straightforward method. Nowadays, hitting `Ctrl+Shift+Del` is fast and works in most browsers, including Internet Explorer.

Comment: Please don't do that. Use shift-reload instead. Don't have your users clear their caches for no reason. A plain reload will often work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP header Last-Modified and Etag use to lessen traffic on the net.

The browser request the web server with `Last-Modified` header. If the date-time same as server file time, the server just response 304. Or, the time is different, the server response 200 and full content.

The Etag do the same process.

There are more like If-Modified-Since , If-Unmodified-Since, see more on
[etag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), and [rfc2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)